# Continuous keypressed functionality for non-arrow keys in Processing

Tags: processing

Please test the following code by pressing (holding down) first the arrow keys and then non-arrow keys.  In Mac at least you'll see the arrow keys apply their functions continuously, whereas the others do not.  Does anyone know how to make the other keys apply continuously in Processing (i.e. not by altering OSX's functionality)?

```
void setup(){}
void draw(){}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode >= 36 && keyCode <= 40) { // keycodes for arrow keys
    println(frameCount + " arrow key activated: " + key);
  } 
  else {
    println(frameCount + " non-arrow key activated: " + key);
  }
}
```

Comment: The example is specifically designed to explain the problem for someone who tries it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a way of doing it. But more like a hack maybe... as it is not dealing with system's key repetition handling. But works :)

```
boolean isPressed;
void setup(){}
void draw(){
  if (isPressed)
  println(frameCount + " non-arrow key activated: " + key);
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode >= 36 && keyCode <= 40) { // keycodes for arrow keys
    println(frameCount + " arrow key activated: " + key);
  } 
  else {
    isPressed = true;
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  isPressed = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @v.k. I was hoping to avoid the boolean proliferation this approach requires for multiple key instructions, but it looks like it may be the easiest workaround.

Comment: actually you need only one boolean to keep track of pressed or not... or maybe i did not understand you... :)

Comment: As I understand it, unless you want all active key actions to be deactivated when any single key is released, you need to add extra logical constraints.

Comment: In reference there is keyTyped() that claims to be aware of key repetitions but did not work here... I'm in a mac. But you can try that... http://processing.org/reference/keyTyped_.html